# View internal networkrequests in windows 8 javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, requirejs, winjs, i18next

I'm helping a developer who has build a website and wants to port it to a windows 8 application. The application has to be build with html and javascript. I got it running, but for some reason requireJS with i18n won't work correctly. Most of the time it does it's job, but some variables won't load the correct information. In a webbrowser I would look at the network request to see what is happening.

Is there a way to see the network requests a windows 8 application does?

*I've tried using fiddler, but it only shows outgoing information. Not the information request information from inside the application.

Comment: are you sure those "requests" go through the network in a windows store app?

Comment: There is a JavaScript console which shows minimal network traffic information (requests out), but there isn't a good network tool built into VSE that I know of.

Comment: I know about the console in VS but it doens't show the information that I need.

about the "request" naming: i didn't know a better name and I think this came the closest because its called this way in the browsers